# How to display Json formated data from laravel backend into vue js GChart(vue-google-charts) using inertia js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, google-visualization, inertiajs

Am trying to display json data from my laravel backend into visual data(graphical),though when i try

```html
<script>
import Layout from '@/Shared/Layout'
import { GChart } from "vue-google-charts";

export default {
    metaInfo: {
        title: 'Dashboard'
    },
    layout: Layout,
    components: {
        GChart,
    },
    props: {
        pie: Object

    },
    data() {
        return {
            chartData: pie,
            options: {
                width: 1100,
                height: 450
            }
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

I get a cart error of "Table has no columns",i have tried adjusting the code to  `chartData:this.pie`
thought in this scenario nothing is displayed hence being puzzled.
Below are some of the screenshots displaying the props from the network inspection tab.
[image]

[["Client","Assets"],["MARKH INVESTMENTS",209]] is a portion of data i want to render in the graph div tag below is a code for also rendering the graph.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 class="mb-8 font-bold text-3xl">Dashboard</h1>
        <p class="mb-8 leading-normal">{{pie}} </p>
        <GChart type="PieChart" :options="options" :data="chartData" />
    </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused when returning data from the props.

```
 props:{
   pie:Object

  },
```

Instead of returning the object,an array had to be returned

```
props:{
   pie:Array

  },
```

Then in the rendering one has to use the this.  property

```
  return {
      chartData:this.pie,
      options: {
        width: 1100,
        height: 450
      }
    };
```